# Redux: Better way for private/public selectors

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

As [this course](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers) suggests, private selectors are **repeated** as public selectors to be used on the full state.

- Private selectors used on slice.
- Public selectors used on full state.

But this will result in:

- Repeating code
- Flooding the the namespace of the public selectors

**Is there a better way to organize selectors?**

### Original example:

Root Reducer & public selector:

```
// reducers/index.js
import todos, * as fromTodos from './todos';

// Reducer
export default combineReducers({
    todos
});

// Private selector
getVisibleTodos(state, filter) {
    return fromTodos.getVisibleTodos(state.todos, filter);
}
```

Slice Reducer & private selector:

```
// reducers/todos.js

// Reducer
export default (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_TODO':
        // ...
        break;
    // Handle other actions ...
    }
}

// Private selector
getVisibleTodos(state, filter) {
    switch(filter) {
    case 'all':
        return todos;
    case 'completed':
        return state.filter(t => t.completed);
    // Other cases ...
    }
}
```

Using the selector:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, {params}) => ({
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state, params.filter || 'all')
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: I've enhanced the example. Notice redefining the selector once as private selector and another time as a public selector. The question is about avoiding this repetition.

Comment: Selectors are usually pure functions so can be moved to their own module without issue.  For inspiration I'd look at [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating private selectors as public selectors has some pros and cons.

I believe that the duplication benefits you in matter of separating concerns and encapsulating logic, i.e. whenever you have to change the logic of fetching some data from redux state you shouldn't have to modify your component.
Furthermore, your component shouln't own the logic of slicing the part of the state that concerns it.

it does, however, incurr in some unnecesarry duplication.
I can think of a solution with [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) libraries, but it might need you to list all selectors in separates files.
With glob, you could iterate through all js files within your selectors folders (you can add complexity to ignore some certain files looking into their instance prototype and what not) and consolidate them in your root reducer file.
I have seen this techniques used in express apps to assemble all routes in one place by creating one js file per route.

Hope its clear and helps you.

**Edit** --> I highly recommend you take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@pearlmcphee/selectors-react-redux-reselect-9ab984688dd4) to get a thorough insight regarding why is it beneficial to duplicate private selectors as public selectors in root reducer (although i know start to think that you could place public selectors in a separate file as well...)